# Taylor-like bound for the matrix exponential tr(exp(X))

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus, trace, matrix-exponential

I am trying to prove the following Taylor-like bound for the the matrix function $F(X) := \operatorname{tr}(\exp(X))$, and symmetric matrices $X, V$ with $\lVert V \rVert \leq 1/2$:
$$
F(X+V) \leq F(X) + \nabla F(X)[V] + 2\nabla^2F(X)[V, V].
$$
Just to be clear, here are the expressions for the directional derivatives from above (I hope that they are correct):
\begin{align*}
\nabla F(X) &= \exp(X) \\
\nabla F(X)[V] &= \operatorname{tr}(\exp(X) V) \\
\nabla^2 F(X)[V, V] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \operatorname{tr}(X^i V X^{n-i} V)
\end{align*}
My proof attempt is as follows: The multivariate Taylor theorem states that there exists $t \in [0, 1]$ such that
$$
F(X+V) = F(X) + \nabla F(X)[V] + \frac12 \nabla^2F(X+tV)[V, V].
$$
Therefore, I have to prove that 
$$
\nabla^2F(X+tV)[V, V] \leq 4 \nabla^2F(X)[V, V].
$$
(numerical experiments suggest that the constant 4 can be replaced with $\sqrt{e}$). It seems to me that it is easy to bound the LHS from above, but I don't see any way of bounding the RHS from below. Does anyone have a pointer or a reference for proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I am actually better off proving a related statement that is easier to use later on
$$
\operatorname{tr}(e^{X+V}) \leq \operatorname{tr}(e^X) + \operatorname{tr}(e^X V) + 2 \operatorname{tr}(e^X V^2).
$$
If $X$ and $V$ commute, this is equivalent to the original statement.

We start by recalling the Golden-Thompson inequality: $\operatorname{tr}(e^{X+V}) \leq \operatorname{tr}(e^X e^V)$ for Hermitian matrices $X$ and $V$. Then, we develop $e^V$ into series and obtain
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}(e^{X+V}) &\leq \operatorname{tr}(e^X e^V) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \operatorname{tr}(e^X V^n) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(e^X) + \operatorname{tr}(e^X V) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\operatorname{tr}(e^X V^n) \\
&\leq \operatorname{tr}(e^X) + \operatorname{tr}(e^X V) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\operatorname{tr}(e^X V^2 |V|^n),
\end{align*}
where $|V|$ is obtained from $V$ by replacing its eigenvalues with their absolute values (i.e. singular values of $V$). We handle the last term by using von Neumann's trace inequality for PSD matrices:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\operatorname{tr}(e^X V^2 |V|^n) &\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_i \lambda_i(e^X V^2) \lambda_i(|V|^n) \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_i \lambda_i(e^X V^2) \lVert V \rVert^n = e^{\lVert V \rVert} \operatorname{tr}(e^X V^2).
\end{align*}
We conclude by noting that $e^{\lVert V \rVert} \leq \sqrt{e} \leq 2$.